# how to read an Object from json file with Gson when there is hashMap in the class

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class that has hashMap in itself, when I get its json file with gson library and want to create it again I'll get some errors.

I tried to create the object again with gson library but it failed.

```
class A{
    private HashMap<String, B> hashMap;
    private int x;
    private String y;
}
class B{/*some simple fields*/}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    A a = new A();
    /*setting fileds*/
    String json = gson.toJson(a);
    A newA = gson.fromJson(json, A.class);
}
```

for example one of errors I caught is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "Name : rostam - AP : 7 - HP : 55 - Class : HYBRID - Special power : "
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:91)
    at controller.AbstractClassAdapters.deserialize(AbstractClassAdapters.java:13)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Please post the actual error

Comment: I added the error to the post
The first line that says it's not a json object is exactly the fields of class B that is inside hashmap

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide string representation of the passed object(here it is A a) into ***fromJson*** method.
Try the below code.

```
String json = gson.toJson(a);
A newA= gson.fromJson(json, A.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
```

It worked for me.